# How do i select multiple values from Multiple select box using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

the multiple select box in which we have to hold the control key and click on the values to select it. how to perform this action using selenium web driver? Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by multiple select box? Is it the check box or something?

As per your description it seems there is a 
"list of items and you want to select multiple items.
say item 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 one below the other and your requirement is to select multiple of them and "do some operation". I guess using selenium you can only select one item at a time and the moment you select the next one the previous one is deselected.

So you want to know can you select multiple items.

Is this your question?

If so then this can be done using Java + selenium.

A robot class in Java can be used to hold your control key then perform a selenium select operation and then release the control key back.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium support classes provide a helper class to work with Select elements, using which one can select/deselect individual/multiple options.

Java:
Use the `Select` support class available in `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui`. Call one of the selectby methods `selectByVisibleText()` to select each item you want.

To deselect all items before performing your selection, use the `deselectAll()` method.

See the Java docs at:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

For .Net, the corresponding class is `SelectElement` in `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`